# AES decode error when using a different AES instance

Tags: c#, aes

I am trying to decode an AES cipher in C#.  If I use the same AES object as when I encode them, everything is fine.  But as soon as I create a different instance of AES, it does not work:

```
        string original = "username,password,companyID";
        byte[] encrypted;
        using (Aes myAes1 = Aes.Create()) {
            encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, GetBytes("password"), myAes1.IV);

            //test1
            string test1 = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, GetBytes("password"), myAes1.IV);
        }
        using (Aes myAes2 = Aes.Create()) {

            //test2
            string test2 = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, GetBytes("password"), myAes2.IV);
        }
```

So in this code, test1 uses myAes1 and it works out fine because the encryption also used myAes1.  However test2 uses myAes2 and it doesn't work, here is the output:

```
test1 = username,password,companyID
test2 = t0�V�e]��Ԅ��yd,companyID
```

what am I doing wrong?

---

Here are the supporting functions, which I copied from online:

```
   static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key,byte[] IV) {
        // Check arguments. 
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        byte[] encrypted;
        // Create an Aes object 
        // with the specified key and IV. 
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create()) {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption. 
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()) {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)) {

                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }


        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream. 
        return encrypted;

    }

    static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV) {
        // Check arguments. 
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        // Declare the string used to hold 
        // the decrypted text. 
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an Aes object 
        // with the specified key and IV. 
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create()) {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption. 
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText)) {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt)) {
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return plaintext;

    }

    static byte[] GetBytes(string str) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you're messing up on character encodings. Difficult to tell what's going on without seeing `EncryptStringToBytes_Aes` and `DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes`.

Comment: Added.  I am not encoding, the code is directly taking from another stackoverflow question on this issue that specifically said to not encode.

Comment: It's probably worth Flushing your StreamWriter before disposing.

Comment: 3 hours ago someone asked an [exact duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18789544/76217) (but didn't post any code so it was impossible to help).

Comment: I guess everyone is having trouble with this.

Comment: @spender - that's what the `using` does. The problem is with the IV. JohnKoerner beat me to it though I'm wondering if the `myAes1.IV` vs `myAes.IV` is a copy/paste error in the question.

Comment: @McAden yes that is an copy/paste error, corrected.

Comment: Although you say this avoids encoding, it's implicitly using UTF16 (this is how .Net stores strings internally), so I would prefer something like `Encoding.UTF16.GetBytes(str)` and `Encoding.UTF16.GetString(byteArrInput)` in your `GetBytes` method. Certainly easier on the eye and less prone to error. You'd save some bytes by switching UTF8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify an IV, then one is randomly generated.  You are using 2 different IV values when decrypting, which is why you are seeing different results.

Comment: What should I use as IV, consider the encoding / decoding happen on different computer, should I just use a secret password that the client don't have access to?

Comment: For AES, the IV should be 16 random bytes. The IV doesn't need to remain secret, it's common practice to prepend the IV to the encrypted byte array after encryption is complete, and then strip it off before decryption.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu: Use the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) to derive both the key and IV from the password.

Comment: @dtb: Rfc2898DeriveBytes is fine for the key, but not for the IV. The IV needs to be random for each encryption so that repeatedly encrypting the same text does not produce identical ciphertext.